# Virtual Machines: High-DPI screen scale resets to 100% when I resize VM's window

Tags: virtualbox, display, screen, vmware, display-resolution

I've installed Ubuntu (tried 17.10 and 18.04 pre-release), since I have a 4k monitor I went to <kbd>Settings</kbd> - <kbd>Devices</kbd> - <kbd>Displays</kbd> and set `Scale` to `200%`.

Everything looks fine until I resize a VM's window (including opening it fullscreen): Ubuntu resets the scale to 100% and everything becomes small.

**How can I avoid this and "lock" the scale at 200%?**

I tried this with `VirtualBox` and `VMWare Player` with the same results.
I know there is a "scale factor" in VirtualBox's settings but it is not the same and it makes pictures blurry.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fire up your terminal and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

In virtualbox i tested it, and i can resize vm window without losing scaling.
This applies to wayland, so 17.10 is best to test this.

Comment: I tried with xorg, working on there too. Tested with virtualbox running on ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and worked. Just note after executing the command, **you need to resize the VM's window to see the effect**.

Comment: What about fractional scaling? 

`$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1.25 =>invalid character in number:  1.25`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VMWare and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; and later 20.04 LTS. I never got `gsettings` to work right. Maybe that's because I have Wayland turned off, as it is broken on my all my VMWare VMs.

Instead, I use this command: `xrandr --output Virtual1 --scale 1.75x1.75`, which seems to work well enough. It doesn't resize until after I log in. The command is persistent, so I haven't added it to any startup scripts or anything.

I don't have any problems with a blurry display, and I definitely have to use a factor greater than zero -- otherwise, the text and user interface elements are very large. It's counter-intuitive, but that's what's working for me!  Maybe two different things are fighting to scale correctly?

Comment: I found that for my 192dpi display that I needed to go the 'opposite' direction and set a scaling value of less than 1: `xrandr --output Virtual1 --scale 0.5x0.5`.

Comment: It does make things larger, but unfortunately it only seems to up-scale the framebuffer resulting in blurry icons and fonts, this setting does not enable high-dpi rendering.